# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for child doesn't have parent set when validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationships

I'm trying to access my parent model in my child model when validating.  I found something about an inverse property on the has_one, but my Rails 2.3.5 doesn't recognize it, so it must have never made it into the release.  I'm not sure if it's exactly what I need though.

I want to validate the child conditionally based on parent attributes.  My Parent model has already been created.  If the child hasn't been created when I update_attributes on the parent, then it doesn't have access to the parent.  I'm wondering how I can access this parent.  It *should* be easy, something like parent.build_child sets the parent_id of the child model, why is it not doing it when building the child for accepts_nested_attributes_for?

For Example:

```
class Parent < AR
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end
class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent
  validates_presence_of :name, :if => :some_method

  def some_method
    return self.parent.some_condition   # => undefined method `some_condition' for nil:NilClass
  end
end
```

My form is standard:

```
<% form_for @parent do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :child do |c| %>
    <%= c.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With an update method

```
def update
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
  @parent.update_attributes(params[:parent])   # => this is where my child validations take place
end
```

Answer (score 14):

I had basically the same problem with Rails 3.2. As suggested in the question, adding the `inverse_of` option to the parent's association fixed it for me.

**Applied to your example:**

```
class Parent < AR
  has_one :child, inverse_of: :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :child
  validates_presence_of :name, :if => :some_method

  def some_method
    return self.parent.some_condition   # => undefined method `some_condition' for nil:NilClass
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem: [Ruby on Rails - nested attributes: How do I access the parent model from child model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611459/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes-how-do-i-access-the-parent-model-from-child-mo)

This is how I solved it eventually; by setting parent on callback

```
class Parent < AR
  has_one :child, :before_add => :set_nest
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child

private
  def set_nest(child)
    child.parent ||= self
  end
end
```

Comment: I had the same error as the op, but when I tried this method I got "Unknown key(s): before_add" ?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this because in-memory child doesn't know the parent its assigned to. It only knows after save. For example.

```
child = parent.build_child
parent.child # => child
child.parent # => nil

# BUT
child.parent = parent
child.parent # => parent
parent.child # => child
```

So you can kind of force this behavior by doing reverse association manually. For example

```
def child_with_inverse_assignment=(child)
  child.parent = self
  self.child_without_inverse_assignment = child
end

def build_child_with_inverse_assignment(*args)
  build_child_without_inverse_assignment(*args)
  child.parent = self
  child
end

def create_child_with_inverse_assignment(*args)
  create_child_without_inverse_assignment(*args)
  child.parent = self
  child
end

alias_method_chain :"child=", :inverse_assignment
alias_method_chain :build_child, :inverse_assignment
alias_method_chain :create_child, :inverse_assignment
```

If you really find it necessary.

P.S. The reason it's not doing it now is because it's not too easy. It needs to be explicitly told how to access parent/child in each particular case. A comprehensive approach with identity map would've solved it, but for newer version there's `:inverse_of` workaround. Some discussions like [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/eaba411bb69c58d8?fwc=1) took place on newsgroups.

Answer (score 0):

check these sites, maybe they'll help you...

[Rails Nested Attributes Association Validation Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102724/rails-nested-attributes-association-validation-failing)

[accepts_nested_attributes_for child association validation failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935650/accepts-nested-attributes-for-child-association-validation-failing)

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

it seems, rails will assign parent_id after child validation succeeds. 
(as parent has an id after it's saved)

maybe worth trying this:

```
child.parent.some_condition
```

instead of self.parent.some_condition ... who knows...