# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for. Use reject_if for rejecting the object by using attributes of the parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models on rails.
The first is the patient model

```
class Patient

attr_accessible :name, :age, :sex, :female_attributes
has_one :female, dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :female, allow_destroy => true

end
```

The second model holds extra info for female patients

```
class Female
belongs_to :patient
attr_accessible :patiend_id, :pregrnant_now: :childbirths
end
```

Note: I didn't create the db schema and i can't change it.

So my question is: how can i reject the female object from being saved in the db by checking the :sex attribute in the patient object?

I tried

```
reject_if => lambda { |a| a['sex'].to_i == 0 ) }
```

but it didn't work. ( sex is an integer and gets 0 for Male and 1 for Female )

Any thoughts??

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5049311/382982) might be helpful. It worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: I tried :before_add => :evaluate_sex and in my patient class i put 
`def evaluate_sex(female)
if female.patient.sex == 0
return true
else 
 return false
end
end`

But it didn't work.

Comment: Solved!!! I added an after_save callback which calls the check_sex functions that destroys the saved female record from the db if its parent object has sex filed set to Male ( if self.patient.sex ==0 self.destroy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old, but I just came across the same problem.  You can use `reject_if` and pass a symbol in your patient model.

```
class Patient

  attr_accessible :name, :age, :sex, :female_attributes
  has_one :female, dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :female,
    reject_if: :female_patient?, 
    allow_destroy => true

  def female_patient?
    self.sex.to_i == 1
  end
end
```