# Rails validation :if not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to validate a model attribute based on a simple condition as shown in the rails docs.  I have a quiz model with a boolean "show_birthday" attribute, and a participant model with a birthday attribute.  Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quiz
    validates :birthday, presence: true, :if => :has_birthday?

    def has_birthday?
        quiz.show_birthday?
    end
end
```

The validation works if I remove the if condition, but does not work even if I change the part inside the has_birthday? method to "true".  Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried using an inline proc?

Comment: I did try that as well.  The code I tried there was:  :if => Proc.new { |p| p.quiz.show_birthday? } (also tried the same thing with an inline lambda)

Comment: is it possible that `Participant` doesn't have a `quiz` record? Although in that case it should raise a nil error...

Comment: In the form view for a new participant I did this <%= "Should validate birthday" if @participant.has_birthday? %> and it shows up when the quiz has show_birthday? marked true...

Comment: define the `has_birthday?` as `self.has_birthday?` and see if it works?

Comment: For code consistency reasons try using only one format of param => value `validates :birthday, :presence => true, :if => :has_birthday?`. This probably isn't the problem with your code, though... it should be working, are you testing in the console and have you restarted said console after changing the validation?

Comment: What happens if you use `:if => "quiz.show_birthday?"` as your `if` clause? (alternative method to check)

Comment: Nothing seems to be working.  If I ad an if clause to any of my validations, they seem to stop working...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5049311/382982) answer?

Comment: I still have no idea why the conditional validation won't fire, but I got around the issue by writing my own.  I'm doing validate :birthday_if_necessary and defining that method which includes a check for whether or not the quiz has show_birthday set to true.