# In Rails, is there an easy way create child objects at the same time as their parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> **Note:** This question was spawned from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778938/) I had regarding the use of accepts_nested_attributes_for. You may reference that question for additional context, if needed.

I believe this question is best explained with a simple example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, inverse_of: :foo
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :foo_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :foo, inverse_of: :bars
end

f = Foo.new()
=> #<Foo id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
b = f.bars.build()
=> #<Bar id: nil, foo_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
f.save!
=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Bars foo can't be blank
```

Is there an easy way to fix this problem? I know that I could save `f` first and then build `b`, but my situation is a little more complex than this example (see the question I referenced above) and I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child records get created at the same time as parent, this is why your validation is failing, your child is not yet persisted. to make it work i would write a custom validation like this

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates_presence_of :bar
end
```

Comment: Ah I see. So I just need to validate the presence of :foo instead of :foo_id. Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to create the object (Maybe before_save?). See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).