# Validate presence of parent for has_many/new_record? situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moves
end

class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :game # validator in question
end

#####

game = Game.new
move = current_user.moves.build
game.moves << move
game.save # => false
game.errors.mesages # => {:"moves.game"=>["can't be blank"]}
```

On `game.save`, ActiveRecord will automatically assign the newly created game to the move. `validates_presence_of :game` throws this off, though, since all the validations (for both game and move) are checked before save. Which totally makes sense.

Removing the `game` constraint on `move` obviously lets the records go through.... BUT I'd like to keep it around since most of the time moves are created in a more standalone fashion. For instance:

```
move      = current_user.moves.build
move.game = @game
move.save
```

**So, my question:** Should I just go ahead and remove that validator, and just ensure `move.game` is always set throughout the codebase? Or is there a magic way to keep it, and still utilize `Game.new.moves << move`

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more research, I figured out there IS a magic way. I just needed to add `inverse_of` options to both sides of the relationship. Not sure exactly how that helps ActiveRecord know how to pass the validator, but it works! Here are the updated models:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moves, inverse_of: :game
end

class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game, inverse_of: :moves
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :game
end

#####

game = Game.new
move = current_user.moves.build
game.moves << move
game.save # => true
```

This answer had the `:inverse_of` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783112/2531850