# Access parent attribute in child model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Working on creating a conditional validation for my model. To check for this I need to check if the Parent.parent_attribute == "true"

```
validates :departure_date, presence: true, future: true, :if => :awesome_method?
 belongs_to :parent


 def awesome_method?
   if @parent.parent_attribute == "true"
     true
   else
     false
   end
 end
```

Currently @parent.parent_attribute is returning nil even though the payload has it. I think I'm running into an issue where it can't access the parent_attribute because it hasn't saved yet... How do I perform a check that the parent has a value before setting a validation?

**Update**
For clarity's sake, I am creating the parent and the child simultaneously.
When I try to use `Parent.find...` I get back

> Couldn't find Parent with 'parent_id'=CORRECT_INVOICE_NAME

**Update 2**
There is a create in both the parent and the child but the following JSON is what creates the parent with child.

```
{
 “parent": {
   “parent_id": "PLZDONTSAVE",
   “data": 2525.25,
   “parent_attribute": true,

   “child_attributes":[
     { “child_toy": “123",
       “child_data": “ABC" }
   ]
 }
}
```

**Parent controller**

```
  def create
    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
    if @parent.save
      render json: @parent, status: :created, location: @parent
    else
      render json: @parent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:parent_id, :parent_attribute,
    child_attributes:[:child_toy, :child_data, ])
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you define `@parent` somewhere, it will be `nil`, just as `@foo` and `@bar`. You can access an object linked via an association (like your `belongs_to`) by simply using `parent` without the "@".

So try this:

```
  def awesome_method?
    parent.parent_attribute == "true"
  end
```

Comment: `parent.parent_attribute` is returning  
> NoMethodError (undefined method `parent_attribute' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: Hm, can you show the code in which you create the parent and the child simultaneously?

Comment: updated my question to demonstrate what I mean by simultaneously building the objects

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like you figured it out, too! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by updating both models with the following. With help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935650/accepts-nested-attributes-for-child-association-validation-failing/4783112#4783112)

In the child model

```
belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :child
```

In the parent model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
```

That coupled with @tbreier's suggestion got the job done.